# Synonyms for "palette"

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for synonyms for "palette," but the usual Google/Thesaurus.com searches fail pretty hard.

I'm interested in the sense that means "the range of color characteristic of a particular artist or painting or school of art."

I'm actually looking for an alternative term for [palette (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palette_%28computing%29) to avoid confusion with something else that was already called a "palette" in the programming library I am using.

So far, the best synonym I've found is "[CLUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palette_%28computing%29#Related_terms_and_technologies)" or [Color Lookup Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_look-up_table).

Comment: ColourSet? ColourTable? ColourScheme? ColourIndex? ColourChart?

Comment: They perhaps have other connotations that may or may not rule them out for you, but _gamut_ or _spectrum_ might meet your need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set of colours that can possibly be created with a given medium is sometimes called a [gamut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamut).

Answer (score 8):

Maybe *spectrum* can work for you.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of a GUI control, I would call it a color chooser or a color selector.

If you are looking for a name for a set of two to four colors that are used predominantly in the interface, then it's the [color scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_scheme) (but FumbleFingers should post that as an answer and get the credit).

Comment: You can have the credit - for distinguishing between the GUI control *(color selector)*, and the actual set of colours controlled by it *(colour scheme)*.